# Total number of learned weights/parameters in CatBoost model?

Tags: random-forest, boosting, catboost

I wasn't really able to find this anywhere in the documentation, or after searching through the model object itself (though it must be there somewhere, of course.  The `_object` attribute of `CatBoostRegressor` has `_get_leaf_weights` and `_get_leaf_values` methods, which return suitably large vectors, but shouldn't there also be weights for each branch point in the set of trees?  These I haven't been able to find.  I would like to report the total number of tuned/learned parameters.

Comment: Actually even that won't be enough because we"learned" where to do splits, per tree. And that is not the same either `leaf_values` or `leaf_weights`. And that will also depend on the tree-building strategy. What is exactly the information we aim to convey here? That somehow  we know how many degrees of freedom we have? Saying simply "*200 trees with median depth 4*" is probably more representative as well as more interpretable of what we actually learned than saying "*2983 leaf values and 2609 internal nodes*".

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more what I mean about the "tree-building strategy":  Growing symmetric trees (CatBoost default) vs growing loss-based (e.g. XGBoost). The symmetric trees "theoretically" have learned less cuts (as the cut is shared among all the nodes in that level). But does that mean we have partitioned our sample space "less than" what if we used loss-based growing strategy given our tree-depth is the same? Of course not, both trees do the same amount recursive partitioning but the one "uses less parameters" to express a base-learner of "comparable complexity".

Comment: Yes, total degrees of freedom is what I'm looking for here.

Comment: In a GBM the concept of DoF is extremely ill-defined. Let's take a step back: even in ridge regression, the DoF are not straightforward as they are affected by the regularisation $\lambda$. In a GBM? With both the leaf and learning rate regularisation, as well as the growth policy, having non-obvious effects on overall fit, the concept of DoF is almost inapplicable. There is some work on the matter (e.g. Reeve and Brown (2018) and Mentch and Zhou (2020)) but those are *really* taking a leap of faith focusing on "effective DoF" (exactly because it is so ill-defined as originally mentioned).

Comment: (+1 one though cause it is a fun question.)